# Can water supply and drain lines be installed on the surface of interior walls?

Tags: plumbing

Hi everyone I'm new here 
I'm renovating a small portable building turning it into a camp and I'm having open cell spray foam insulation installed and don't want to undo the sound damping of the foam with a alot of holes.
I'm trying to find out if code friendly to install water lines and drain lines on the walls instead of in them?

These are all interior walls freezing isn't really an issue but all pipes will be easily accessible from inside. Where all plumbing and water connection to main lines and septic tank shall be insulated and protected. I'm trying to avoid corrupting the spray foam due to extreme loud neighbors,

Answer (score 3):

Piping exterior of walls is not a problem.  Just use install pipe based on the additional environmental conditions such as abrasion or temperature.  This means using copper, galvanized, or other piping that can be "abused" and adding heat tape and insulation as req'd or the ability to drain during times of freezing temperature for areas susceptible to freezing.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with that at all, although any dreams you may have had of a career in interior design made have just taken a more... 'industrial' turn...